# архитектура простого сервера чисто для i/o на диск

Tags: сервер, архитектура

здравствуйте, вопрос такой: имеет ли смысл писать сервер типа "один поток(из пула) на одно соединение" если вся работа после принятия данных это работа с диском(файлами на диске) и базой данных? или стоит сделать как-то по-другому

я так думаю, что i/o совершенно не грузит процессор, поэтому поток на соединение будет слишком затратно

Answer (score 1):

Потоки дешевые, синхронизация потоков дорогая.

Синхронный, последовательный код, где синхронизация и паралельность не критична, лучше работает в пуле потоков, и даже в пуле процессов.

Асинхронный код лучше работает в одном потоке на ядро.

Comment: а если 100к соединений?

Comment: то это 10кбит/с на соединение при гигабитном интернете. тут пул серверов надо.

так в каком стиле будет писаться код?

Comment: ну я имею ввиду если ежесекундно подключается/отключается много тысяч клиентов, но сервер чисто для i/o, то будет ли асинхронный сервер выигрывать у многопоточного.?

Comment: по мировому опыту на мелких запросах асинхронные выигрывают